# Create a totally new PHP page and pull Woocommerce data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to PHP.  I have been a .net programmer for 20 years but php is new.  I would like to create a totally isolated page and access the WooCommerce data to perform some specific needs but I don't know where to start other than creating a "mypage.php".

I don't now what I need to do to connect to the DB and/or what to use to begin communicating with WooCommerce.  I have seen many examples of interacting with WooCommerce and, in fact, I have been quite successful changing things within established pages but this is for a brand new page that is not generated by WooCommerce itself.

If someone could point me to an example on how to get started I can take it from there.

Comment: I think you must start from "page template" concept in wordpress.

Comment: Depending on the task, I think "Shortcodes" can help you. I use them when i was starting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @mohammad, I had to start from a wordpress template.  You pointed me to the right thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need create new page, so you can try

```
Wordpress page template
```

If you need connect to DB, so you need use

```
global $wpdb
```

for query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your PHP code is on a wordpress page you can access the woocommerce objects directly. ie: `$order = wc_get_order( 212 ); $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();` will give you data from order number 212.

A good place to start is [woocommerce's code reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/)